# xmlrpc vs json / rest on java google appengine with android client

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, rest, xml-rpc

Can someone please point me to a reference which gives a "full circle" example implementation of either (both with android client and java appengine back end) xmlrpc or json / rest ? I have found a python example but am struggling to find a java version.

Bonus points (not really) but if anyone could provide one where the the transport mechanism is abstracted out so the two are interchangable, I would be eternally in their favour. Any they'd get a credit in the software I'm putting together for this (for what it's worth).

Thanks,

Richard.

Comment: this is not a SO question, this is a consulting job!

Comment: Hi dfa - it's not an ongoing consultancy - it's just asking for a word from the wise about libraries that are tried and tested, as opposed to me going down a route that ends up with "version x.y of z lib needs version a.b of c lib and they don't work together". Believe me, if someone could give me references to 2 x xmlrpc libs (1 client, 1 server) and 2 x json (ditto) then I'd be a happy man !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For XMLRPC, I made a while ago a MetaWeblogAPI (which Blogger uses) backend for running under GAE.

I kept the sources at [BitBucket](http://hg.modafocas.org/nullweblog). As for a client, well, I am using Apache XMLRPC, so it should be easy to implement. Anyway, you would use either Word and/or Windows Live Writer as a testing for this particular case.

Comment: Only one answer? Ok.. here's the green tick!