# Can't find the function name

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm creating a webservice for appengine, and I've created two functions inside the class WebService.py. And I'm trying to register these functions in a SimpleXMLRPCServer object. But When I pass the function names to the parameters, it says undefined variable.

Here is the code:

```
import SimpleXMLRPCServer

from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext import db

class WebService(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def login(self, username, password):

        calls = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * from User ORDER BY username DESC LIMIT 10")

        for call in calls:
            if calls.username == username and calls.password == password:
                return True
        return False

    def register(self, username, password):

        db.GqlQuery("INSERT into User (username, password) value(%s, %s)"%(username, password))
        return True

 server = SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer(('localhost',8080))
 server.register_function(login)
 server.register_function(register)
 server.serve_forever()
```

Is this the right way to do it?? If its not, can you please tell me what is wrong in my code??

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try `WebService.login` and `Webservice.register`?

Comment: You *really* don't want to make these methods of your RequestHandler. Of course, you can't actually run a server on port 8080 within App Engine at all, so you don't want to do this at all.

Comment: You need to decide what you're doing -- building an app engine app, or a SimpleXMLRPCServer app.

Comment: Try making them free / module level functions (without the `self`) and then register them with the server -- that is, if what you want is SXRS not GAE.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding though -- why do you want to use SXRS and webapp at the same time?

Comment: What I want is simply create a webservice for appengine with Python, and later integrate it with android. But first what I need is create a webservice for appengine. Can you help me with that??

Comment: Have you gone through any Google App engine tutorials? You don't want the simple xml-rpc server (probably) you want something like CGIXMLRPCRequestHandler

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331600/how-to-write-a-web-service-for-google-app-engine

Comment: and also http://brizzled.clapper.org/id/80/

Comment: Here is another question about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253937/xmlrpc-vs-json-rest-on-java-google-appengine-with-android-client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out! I'm still newbie to python, so it is a newbie doubt.

Looks like the problem was with the identation. I needed to put it inside the class identation, so it could find the method.

In fact, it should be like this:

```
import SimpleXMLRPCServer

from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext import db

class WebService(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def login(self, username, password):

        calls = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * from User ORDER BY username DESC LIMIT 10")

        for call in calls:
            if calls.username == username and calls.password == password:
                return True
        return False

    def register(self, username, password):

        db.GqlQuery("INSERT into User (username, password) value(%s, %s)"%(username, password))
        return True

    server = SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer(('localhost',8080))
    server.register_function(login)
    server.register_function(register)
    server.serve_forever()
```

This solved my problem. Thank you for your replies.

Comment: Do you really want to start serving in a class definition? No, you don't. This may have solved the short-term problem, but it's not correct.

Comment: See my answers on the question. You can do xml-rpc with app engine, but not this way.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to pass global objects `login` and `register` to `register_function()`, but those aren't global objects, they're methods.

I'm assuming you either need to instantiate that class and pass the attributes of that object in or you need to pass the attributes of the class as the commenter suggested.